# Ini file Type name Expected C++

Tags: c++, file, c++builder, ini

I hope that you can help me to resolve this compilation error.

I'm trying to test code taken from Embarcadero's official documentation website, which has at aim to test the `TIniFile` class.

However I get this error:

```
Unit2.cpp(76): parsing: TCustomIniFile * _fastcall Form2::OpenIniFileInstance().
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
#include <IniFiles.hpp>

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm2 *Form2;

__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}

void __fastcall TForm2::btStoreClickClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    //First Edit of the file
     /* Open an instance */
    TCustomIniFile* SettingsFile = OpenIniFileInstance();

    // Store current form properties to be used in later sessions.
    try
    {
        SettingsFile->WriteInteger (Name, "Top", Top);
        SettingsFile->WriteInteger (Name, "Left", Left);
        SettingsFile->WriteInteger (Name, "Width", Width);
        SettingsFile->WriteInteger (Name, "Height", Height);
        SettingsFile->WriteString  (Name, "Caption", Caption);
        SettingsFile->WriteBool    (Name, "InitMax", WindowState == wsMaximized );
    }
    catch(Exception* e)
    {
    }

    delete SettingsFile;

}

void __fastcall TForm2::btLoadClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TCustomIniFile* SettingsFile = OpenIniFileInstance();

    try
    {
        /*
        Read all saved values from the last session. The section name
        is the name of the form. Also use form's properties as defaults
        */
        Top     = SettingsFile->ReadInteger(Name, "Top", Top );
        Left    = SettingsFile->ReadInteger(Name, "Left", Left );
        Width   = SettingsFile->ReadInteger(Name, "Width", Width );
        Height  = SettingsFile->ReadInteger(Name, "Height", Height );
        Caption = SettingsFile->ReadString (Name, "Caption", Caption);

        // Load last window state
        if (SettingsFile->ReadBool(Name, "InitMax", WindowState == wsMaximized))
            WindowState = wsMaximized;
        else
            WindowState = wsNormal;
    }
    catch(Exception* e)
    {
    }

    delete SettingsFile;
}

TCustomIniFile* __fastcall TForm2::OpenIniFileInstance()
{
    TCustomIniFile* temp;
    switch (RadioGroup1->ItemIndex)
    {
        case 0: {
                /* Registry mode selected: in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\... */
            temp = new TRegistryIniFile(String("Software\\") + Application->Title);
        }  
            break;
        case 1: {
                /* Ini file mode selected */
            temp = new TIniFile(ChangeFileExt(Application->ExeName, ".INI"));
        }
            break;
        case 2: {
                /* Memory based Ini file mode selected */
            temp = new TMemIniFile(ChangeFileExt(Application->ExeName, ".INI"));
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Where is line 76 where the error happens? Also note, that `temp` in `OpenIniFileInstance` is not inialized, when the `default`-case is hit for some reason you are returning a garbage pointer.

Comment: I thank you for your answer. Even I remove the the 'default' case I get same error. I think that the error is more deeper than initialisation issue.

Comment: That was more a question about where line 76 is ;)  And the thing about `default`-cases is, that usually when they are hit, something went wrong. In your case, when the `default` is hit, think about what value will be returned and if this is a wanted behaviour.

Comment: the line 76 is `case 0` in my code : ` temp = new TRegistryIniFile(String("Software\\") + Application->Title);`

Comment: P.S: I get this code from this [link]http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/IniFiles_TCustomIniFile.html  with a slight modification.

Comment: The title of the question is about "type name expected". The error message that you include in the question doesn't include this information. I think you should show the actual and complete error messages. If there are additional messages from the compiler it would make it probably easier to answer the question. -- Please keep in mind that only a few StackOverflow user might have the Borland compiler to do a deeper look.

Comment: Thanks harper for your answer. The error comes from the type TRegistryIniFile. I don't know which header to include or which cast to do to resolve this error. I have done a test by just make as a comment the line 76 and then I get no error and I can execute the program correctly. The adding of the header file  `<IniFiles.hpp>` is not enough for the compiler.

Comment: But you wrote the line in question is "case 0:". There is no type `TRegistryIniFile` in that line. -- If you don't know the correct header file to include, try to search the class name with a text editor like NotePad++ or probably the embarcadero IDE.

Comment: @harper: Thanks. I have find this description  about the  [Link](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Registry_TRegistryIniFile.html) for the `TRegistryIniFile` Class from embarcadero but I don' t have any idea what to do exactly to resolve this issue.

Comment: I wrote two recommendations in my last comments. Use it or ignore it, as you like.

Comment: I have find the solution. I have to add this header file `#include<System.Win.Registry.hpp>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody.
I have find the solution to resolve this issue. I miss the header file `#include<System.Win.Registry.hpp>`

Best regards.